# Cannot load image greater than 2000 pixel android

Tags: android

Hi I want to load image from my phone memory and put it on ImageView. This is my code for loading image:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        mImageCaptureUri = selectedImage;
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);


        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        isBackgroundChange = true;

    }
```

}

This code is working but everytime I load big images(resolution) the application closes.

Comment: It happens because of high resolution images...

Comment: What is the solution for that?

Comment: you have to resize that images without effects its resolution...

Comment: Do you have sample code that fits my code above?